# How to change daily transaction limit of paytm gateway

Tags: wordpress, paytm

Hi i am doing a hotel room booking reservation system in word press.i am using paytm as my payment gateway. Every thing works fine but if the transaction amount is greater than 10000 transaction cannot be processed and redirect back to the home page itself
the url i got is

```
http://samajamkochi.com/?msg=Thank+you+for+shopping+with+us.+However%2C+the+transaction+has+been+Failed+For+Reason++%3A+Max+Txn+amount+is+crossed+for+Cust+Id&type=error
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. As per RBI rules a standard user can do upto INR 10000/month. To transact more than that user has to upgrade his/her account.